# How can I add an MDDataTable to a Screen in a class that's not the main app class?

Tags: kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to create an app where after you log in you're shown a table of users. If the login is successful I want the user to be sent to another screen that has an MDDataTable in it.

All of the examples I've found online only show how to display the table using the build method in the main app.

Code example:

```
class ScreenOne(Screen):
    # Displays MDDataTable without the need to press anything to view the table.

class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    # When this screen validates user successfully it sends
    # me to the other screen that shows an
    # MDDataTable and not a blank screen etc...

sm = ScreenManager()

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        sm.add_widget(ScreenOne(name='screenone'))
        sm.add_widget(ScreenTwo(name='screentwo'))
        return sm

MainApp().run()
```

I keep getting either a blank screen or the following error:
`ValueError: KivyMD: App object must be initialized before loading root widget. See https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/wiki/Modules-Material-App#exceptions`

I kept changing the code trying to fix it but I just kept running into all sorts of errors and problems and I just don't understand enough to make my question any clearer.

Here's my `.py` file code:

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.stacklayout import MDStackLayout
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout


class ClientsTable(Screen):
    def load_table(self):
        layout = Screen()
        data_tables = MDDataTable(
            size_hint=(0.9, 0.6),
            use_pagination=True,
            check=True,
            column_data=[
                ("No.", dp(30)),
                ("Column 1", dp(30)),
                ("Column 2", dp(30)),
                ("Column 3", dp(30)),
                ("Column 4", dp(30)),
                ("Column 5", dp(30)),],
            row_data=[
                (f"{i + 1}", "2.23", "3.65", "44.1", "0.45", "62.5")
                for i in range(50)],)
        layout.add_widget(data_tables)
        return layout

class LoginPage(Screen):
    username = ObjectProperty()
    password = ObjectProperty()

    def validate_user(self):
        if self.username.text == "m":
            sm.current = "Clientstable"
            self.username.text = ""
            self.password.text = ""
        else:
            print("Not here!")


sm = ScreenManager()

class MainWindow(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "EasySport"
        sm.add_widget(LoginPage(name='Loginpage'))
        sm.add_widget(ClientsTable(name='Clientstable'))
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainWindow().run()
```

`.kv` code:

```
ScreenManager:
    LoginPage:
    ClientsTable:


<LoginPage>:
    username: User
    password: Pass
    MDTextField:
        id: User
        hint_text: "Username"
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.09
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.7}
    MDTextField:
        id: Pass
        hint_text: "Password"
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.09
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.6}
    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        text: "Login"
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.06
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.4}
        on_release: 
            root.validate_user()
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'



<ClientsTable>:
    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        text: "Back"
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.06
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.4}
        on_release: 
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            root.manager.current = 'Loginpage'
    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        text: "Load Table"
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.06
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.3}
        on_release: 
            root.load_table()
```

Now it doesn't do anything when I press the `Load Table` button!

Comment: You'll need to revise your question to explain what the problem is more specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I SOLVED IT!

Here's the `.py` file code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.stacklayout import MDStackLayout
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout




class ClientsTable(Screen):
    def load_table(self):
        layout = AnchorLayout()
        self.data_tables = MDDataTable(
            pos_hint={'center_y': 0.5, 'center_x': 0.5},
            size_hint=(0.9, 0.6),
            use_pagination=True,
            check=True,
            column_data=[
                ("No.", dp(30)),
                ("Column 1", dp(30)),
                ("Column 2", dp(30)),
                ("Column 3", dp(30)),
                ("Column 4", dp(30)),
                ("Column 5", dp(30)),],
            row_data=[
                (f"{i + 1}", "2.23", "3.65", "44.1", "0.45", "62.5")
                for i in range(50)],)
        self.add_widget(self.data_tables)
        return layout

    def on_enter(self):
        self.load_table()


class LoginPage(Screen):

    username = ObjectProperty()
    password = ObjectProperty()

    def validate_user(self):
        if self.username.text == "m":
            sm.current = "Clientstable"
            self.username.text = ""
            self.password.text = ""
        else:
            print("Not here!")

sm = ScreenManager()

class MainWindow(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        sm.add_widget(LoginPage(name='Loginpage'))
        sm.add_widget(ClientsTable(name='Clientstable'))
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainWindow().run()
```

And the `.kv` file code:

```
ScreenManager:
    LoginPage:
    ClientsTable:


<LoginPage>:
    username: User
    password: Pass
    MDTextField:
        id: User
        hint_text: "Username"
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.09
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.7}
    MDTextField:
        id: Pass
        hint_text: "Password"
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.09
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.6}
    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        text: "Login"
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.06
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.4}
        on_release: 
            root.validate_user()
```

I just needed to add the `Screen`'s `on_enter()` method to my class like it says in the documentation. See [here](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/screen/#kivymd.uix.screen.MDScreen)